# Pointers in C — adding 1

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I have a question about pointers.  I am beginning to grasp the concept, but this particular piece of code is threatening that understanding, and I just want to clear it up.

Please note line "B", which is    `printf("ptr + %d = %d\n",i, *ptr++);   /*<--- B*/`

I was under the impression that, since `*ptr` was initialized to `&my_array[0]`, then `*ptr++` (which would translate to "whatever is at the address stored in `ptr`, add one to it") would print out 23, which is the value at `my_array[1]`.

Yet, it prints out the value at `my_array[0]`, which is `1`.

I'm confused as to whether the `++` adds to the address itself (like, 1004 becomes 1005) and, since the integer takes up about 4 bytes of space, it would fall into the range of `my_array[0]` (because that value, 1, would take up addresses 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, and since `my_array[0]` starts out at 1001 and only goes up to 1002, then `*ptr++` would still print out `my_array[0]`, which is `1`)...

or...

Whether `*ptr++` goes from `my_array[0]` (which is just `*ptr`) to `my_array[1]` `*ptr++`, which is what I originally thought.

Basically, please explain what `*ptr++` does to this program in particular.  Please explain it to me as though I was a five year old.

I really appreciate it, and here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_array[] = { 1, 23, 17, 4, -5, 100 };
int *ptr;

int main(void)  
{ 
    int i;
    ptr = &my_array[0];     /* point our pointer to the first
                                  element of the array */
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("my_array[%d] = %d   ", i, my_array[i]);   /*<-- A */
        printf("ptr + %d = %d\n", i, *ptr++);   /*<--- B*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:
`printf("ptr + %d = %d\n",i, *ptr++); /*<--- B*/`

to this:
`printf("ptr + %d = %d\n",i, *(++ptr)); /*<--- B*/`

When you use the postfix version if the increment operator, the value of the object before the increment is returned by value by the expression.  The prefix increment operator (which the second set of code in this answer uses) will return the incremented object by reference.

Comment: +1 for correctly describing how postfix actually works. It is honestly surprising how many people think the increment happens after the *statement* rather than how you described it, returning the prior value. It is one of the reasons they're most expensive to implement in languages like C++, since temp-copies of state must be made.

Comment: So *ptr++ increments after the printf, and *(++ptr) increments before the printf, which prints out the modified value.

Comment: And *++ptr would be the same as *(++ptr).  Thanks!

Comment: For your purposes, that is what the behavior appears like, but more precisely, the expression `*(ptr++)` returns a copy of object that is pointed to by the unincremented `*ptr` and the expression `*(++ptr)` returns the object pointed to by the incremented `*ptr` by reference.

Comment: There is a sequence point before the function call, so the arguments to `printf()` — and any function — are fully evaluated, including side-effects such as increments, before the function call is made.  You can't rely on the order of evaluation of the arguments in the call (officially).  There's another sequence point when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

*ptr++ will increment after the printf. You should use *(++p).